# iOS POST request with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to make a POST request to a web service

This is the JSON that I need to send-

```
{
   “LinkedTo” : {
                            “IndividualStakeholder” : “”,
                            “GroupedStakeholder” : “”,
                            “LandParcelStakeholder” : “”,
                            “Communications” : “”,
                            “Team” : “”,
                            “Issue” : “”,
                            “Event” : “”
                        }
   “userId” : 170,
   “projectId”: 12
}
```

This is the code I am using -

```
NSString *jsonData = [self JSONString:jsonData1];
```

The value in `NSString *jsonData` at this point is

> {\"LinkedTo\":{\"IndividualStakeholder\":\"\",\"GroupedStakeholder\":\"\",\"LandParcelStakeholder\":\"\",\"Communications\":\"\",\"Team\":\"\",\"Issue\":\"\",\"Event\":\"\"},\"userId\":170,\"projectId\":4}

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://somedomain.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             jsonData, @"jsonText" , nil];
NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"https://somedomain.com/api/stakeholders" parameters:params];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
        NSLog(@"Inside the success block %@",JSON);
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
        NSLog(@"json text is: %@", JSON);
        NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];
[operation start];



-(NSString*)JSONString :(NSString*)aString{
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithString:aString];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"\\/" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\b" withString:@"\\b" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\f" withString:@"\\f" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@"\\r" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@"\\t" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    return [NSString stringWithString:s];
}
```

**The error on the server is** - Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/stakeholders'. Which is an error in asp.net throws when deserializing the posted JSON

The output I am receiving on the client is

Request failed with error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code [number of indexes: 100 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (200-299)], got 500" UserInfo=0x8e95e60 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://somedomain.com/api/stakeholders, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code [number of indexes: 100 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (200-299)], got 500}, {
    NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://somedomain.com/api/stakeholders";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Expected status code [number of indexes: 100 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (200-299)], got 500";
}
2013-02-25 11:03:44.669 NetworkPlugin[60069:c07]

Comment: 500 is an internal server error, check the server's error logs.

Comment: The error on the server is - Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/stakeholders'. Which is an error in asp.net throws when deserializing the posted JSON

Comment: That error doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the JSON. Are you sure you have a route set up for /stakeholders, and it's set to take POST requests?

Comment: yes. I am able to make the POST request to the same server from a website using JQuery

Comment: Check out `AFHTTPClient`'s `setParameterEncoding` method with `AFJSONParameterEncoding` so the post will actually have a valid JSON HTTP body.

Comment: @KeithSmiley, this solved my problem. Thanks. If you want to post it as the answer, I will accept.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal thanks posted! Wasn't sure enough about it. Just ran into that problem myself the other day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `AFHTTPClient`'s `setParameterEncoding` method with `AFJSONParameterEncoding` so the post will actually have a valid JSON HTTP body. Declared and commented [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h#L474-L492)

Answer (score 1):

What I see is you are sending `","` instead of values such as `"15", "18"` etc. Try modifying your json data using correct JSONKit functions.

Comment: I think you're mis-counting quotes, it's well-formed json.

Comment: The values in the fields IndivdualStakeholders, GroupedStakeholder, etc are optional. But the ASP.net server requires me to pass empty values in anyway.